# How to describe tags?

Tags: discussion

I came across description of tags at the following convention (I took badminton as an example):

> Questions about rules, equipment and training related to badminton.

I think that an Excerpt about tag should be a real explanation of the tag and not a general convention as above.

We all know this web site design for questions so i think that the explanation should be like this (again I took badminton as an example):

> Badminton is a racquet sport played by opposing players who take
>   positions on opposite halves of a rectangular court that is divided by
>   a net. Players score points by striking a shuttlecock with their
>   racquet so that it passes over the net and lands in their opponents'
>   half of the court.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Tags should be described by their *usage* not a description of the sport or activity.